# div not working as I expect it to

Tags: assembly, x86

The value in eax after this operation, from how I understand it, should be 64. The value of eax is 00008677, instead. If I am mistaken, could someone explain why? If I'm wrong (which I am definitely wrong), could someone help me get the answer that I am expecting, in a register that I can use? All help is appreciated.

```
    mov eax, 8000000
    mov ebx, 125000
    div ebx
    dump_regs 1
```

EAX = 00008677 after this. I expected 64.

Comment: Did you remember to zero `edx`? The `div` instruction divides the 64-bit value in `edx:eax` by the dividend.

Comment: If EOF's answer isn't it, get GDB to highling which registers were modified after every instruction.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Setting edx to 0 gives me   EAX = 00000040; still not 64, though, like it should be.

Comment: @AustinDonley Um... 40 base 16 == 64 base 10.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct.